# What's a good alternative to Dopplr?

Tags: online-resources, planning, mobile-apps

From the [Dopplr website](http://www.dopplr.com/):

> Dopplr is a service for smart
>   international travellers. Dopplr
>   members share personal and business
>   travel plans privately with their
>   networks, and exchange tips on places
>   to stay, eat and explore in cities
>   around the world.

Since Nokia bought Dopplr it's been dead in the water. I'm looking for something that offers similar features to keep track of where I've been, distance travelled, etc. And also maybe Yelp-like features that recommends places to visit.

Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know any off the top of my head. If this garners enough interest I'd love to sit down and chat and build something.

Answer (score 10):

I have never used Dopplr but from what I see it seems very similar to [TripIt](http://www.tripit.com/), which is a popular option for itinerary tracking/planning. Depending on what place you're visiting, [Lonely Planet has a selection of mobile apps](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/mobile/) for recommendations and places to see. I also use [Foursquare](http://www.foursquare.com) to keep a log of places I have visited, and it can sometimes be good for recommendations too.

Comment: Agreed - TripIt does basically everything that Dopplr does, and more. TripIt's Pro service may be worth paying for if you travel a lot, particularly by air - they provide automatic notifications of gates/flight changes etc. by SMS/email, amongst other things.

Answer (score 9):

I used [dopplr](http://www.dopplr.com/) for a while before switching to [tripit](http://www.tripit.com/). It is basically the same service. Add your travels and your friends can see where you are. The dopplr site looks nicer but lacks the outstanding mail importer of tripit. Just forward a flight booking andit gets into your new or existing travel. Tripit was also first with linkedin integration. I don't know if dopplr is there yet. Probably not given their new owner structure....

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Dopplr either, but based on your description I would say [Google places](http://places.google.com)  and [Google Latitude](http://latitude.google.com) is doing some of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [InTractu](http://www.intractu.com/) service to keep not only places, but also ways I've been traveling. It remembers the ways and is able to visualize them all on the map.

For now it works only on mobile devices, but sometime soon I will release www version, showing traces of flights, visited cities and some other data that can be extracted from GPS data the phone is gathering.